# How to encrypt Credentials object - Cipher.doFinal, SealedObject, or CipherOutputStream?

Tags: java, encryption

I need to encrypt a set of user credentials and send it to a SOAP web service. The following code snippet (I think it's C#) is provided in the documentation, and my Java code is based on it.

```
private string Encrypt256(string text, AesCryptoServiceProvider aes)
{
    // Convert string to byte array
    byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
    // encryption
    using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
    {
        byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
        // Convert byte array to Base64 strings
        return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
    }
}
...
Credentials credential = new Credentials();
credential.UserName = "username";
credential.Password = "password";
credential.ClientUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//--Serialize credential
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(credential.GetType());
string xmlCredential = string.Empty;
using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, credential);
    xmlCredential = stringwriter.ToString();
}
//--Encrypt credential with AES256 symmetric
String encryptedCredential = Encrypt256(xmlCredential, aesServiceProvider);
...
```

The following is my Java code.

```
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kg.init(256);
SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();
Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
Credentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");//no need for time field?
String eCred = Base64.encodeBase64String(aesCipher.doFinal(objectToByteArray(cred)));

...

private byte[] objectToByteArray(Object obj) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try (
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    ) {
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Then I came across `SealedObject` and `CipherOutputStream`. I tried writing code snippets for those.

Using **SealedObject**

```
// slight change here; cred must implement Serializable
UsernamePasswordCredentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");

// same as above except for the following two lines
SealedObject so = new SealedObject(cred, aesCipher);
String eCred = Base64.encodeBase64String(objectToByteArray(so));
```

Using **CipherOutputStream**

```
Credentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, aesCipher);
cos.write(objectToByteArray(cred));
cos.close();

String eCred = Base64.encodeBase64String(bos.toByteArray());
```

For all three code snippets, is the code correct? Considering that this code will be called frequently, which approach is the most efficient?

Comment: Neither Java method is using XML serialization so if your goal is to be compatible with the C# code on XML level then you failed. Using a `Cipher` with just `"AES"` will default to the insecure ECB mode for the default provider in Java - that's certainly not something you want.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes in that case what would you suggest? I'm sort of new to encryption, so I'd appreciate as much advice as I can get.

Comment: Nothing really. The C# code is faulty as it by default uses CBC mode and a random IV. So whatever it is creating as ciphertext, the first block cannot be decrypted afterwards. I would ask the SOAP provider for the protocol specification and implement that in Java.